# Error when trying to start the react native app

Tags: react-native

I am getting the below error when trying to start my react-native app. I have updated the react-native version and this issue started to occur.

**Eroror:-**

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve "./AR" from "node_modules/expo/build/deprecated.js"
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-video-player": "^1.5.8",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.33.0",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-triangle": "0.0.9",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.5.1",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.13",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0", 
    "expo": "~38.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.10",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "~0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.11.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2"
  },
```

Can anyone please help what am I doing wrong? Seems to an issue with the dependencies version.

Comment: having the same problem after doing npm-check-updates ncu -u

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the Metro bundler cache did the trick for me:

`expo start -c`